# Are there any repercussions from having an Israeli stamp in my passport?

Tags: visas, passports, israel, passport-stamps

I have heard people say that having a stamp from Israel in your passport can cause problems when trying to get into other countries.

Is there any truth to this statement? If so, which countries does it create issues with?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, having an Israeli stamp in your passport can restrict your ability to enter some Islamic and Arab nations including:

- Syria
- Lebanon
- Libya
- Kuwait
- Iran
- Iraq
- Pakistan
- Saudi Arabia
- Sudan
- Yemen

What to do about it? Here are some options...

1. **Don't worry about it** -- If you aren't interested in travelling to any of these countries, it doesn't matter if you have an Israeli stamp. This is the simplest option.
2. **Stamp separate paper** - Israeli passport control is amenable to stamping a separate piece of paper rather than stamping your passport. However, be aware that this may not be sufficient for hiding your visit to Israel. For example, if you cross a border on land (e.g. Jordan or Egypt), you will have the stamp from the nation on the other side of the border crossing, so not having an Israeli stamp isn't fooling anyone.
3. **Renew passport** - Simply get a new passport after visiting Israel. Then you can travel on your new passport to any of the above mentioned nations. This is an especially good option if your passport is getting close to the expiry date and/or you don't have any immediate plans to visit the countries in question.
4. **Second passport** - Some nations (at least in Europe) will actually issue a second passport for the purpose of travelling to Israel. The US does not do this, however, it isn't hard to get a second US passport for other valid reasons (such as needing to travel while your passport is away for visa processing). If taking this options, it is advised that you do not travel with both passports. Do not take a passport with an Israeli stamp to one of the listed nations even if you do not present it to officials as it may be found if your possessions are searched.

It is probably best not to visit Israel and one of these arab nations on the same trip as it is harder to conceal the visit (see note above about land border crossings). Other evidence of visiting Israel may also be problematic. I've heard of receipt/stamps from a hostel in Israel as cause for ejection from an arab country.

*Source: written from memory though I believe most of the info came from the Lonely Planet guidebook*

Comment: What do you mean by "receipt/stamps from a hostel"? Papers? Or the fact you have been in this hostel?

Comment: Well presumably if you have a receipt from 'Israel Traveller's Hostel" in your bag, it'd be evidence of you being in Israel.  Even an ATM slip with a bank address on it would be evidence...

Comment: I don't remember the exact scenario about the hostel, but as Mark Mayo says, if they go through your bag any kind of evidence is sufficient.

Comment: Fifth option: paste postage stamps or something else on top of the israeli stamp in the passport.

Comment: while in Egypt I meet a guy who chose to avoid not being allowed into the likes of Syria Iran and Lebanon after visiting Israel by visiting them first then Israel. This caused him issues when he arrived in Israel. He told me he was detained for several hours and escorted around the airport on both visits with out his shoes on and with only his passport and cash in a clear plastic bag.

Comment: Wikitravel also mentions Afghanistan, Algeria and Somalia  also wont' let people with Israel stamps in.

Comment: @Stuart: See my answer here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/will-an-iranian-or-kuwaiti-visa-or-stamp-in-my-passport-pose-a-problem-on-a-futur/2111#2111

Comment: According to the German foreign ministry web site, you should now be able to enter Pakistan with an Israeli stamp, while this used to be a problem in the past. I would still try to double check before doing this.

Comment: @Jostein that would be tampering with a passport which in many (most?) countries is a crime and would invalidate the entire document.

Comment: Having just flown to Israel if you want them to stamp another piece of paper you ask for a '17L' which is the card they stamp. However @g. said this would be pointless for crossing via land, further to that a friend of mine requested a 17L at the Jordan/Israel border and was refused on the grounds that it is pointless.

Comment: You won't get your passport stamped in Israel if you ask them not to stamp it - they're very well aware of the problem. I don't know about the land crossings (which are all on borders with Arab countries, that's why it may be pointless - they know you're going to Israel anyway and probably share the data amongst their border police units), but at the airport - you just need to ask (and some reported that the border control ask themselves if you care to have a stamp in the passport or on a separate form).

Comment: The US *does* issue second passports for this purpose, though it requires a special application and the second one is only valid for 2 years.  See [here](http://jerusalem.usconsulate.gov/second-valid-passports.html). I know someone who has done this.

Comment: @littleadv It is pointless because your passport has or will get stamped on the other side and there is only one country you could have come from or exited to at any of these border crossings. It's not Egypt or Jordan that are making problems (beyond not getting out of their way to accommodate you) but other countries using this information to deduce that you have, in fact, been to Israel. I have never heard of any specific information sharing scheme between the countries on the list (it includes Iran and Iraq!) and the fact that Egypt and Jordan are “Arab countries” thus appears irrelevant.

Comment: Am update to this answer, now Israel does not stamp your passport at all.  They give you an entry card instead.