# I would like to visit Israel. How can I work or visit after that in UAE?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, israel, uae

I would like to visit Israel. How can I work or visit after that in UAE? I have an Indian Passport.

Comment: Related: [Will a UAE stamp in my passport cause problems entering Israel?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9418/108)

Comment: Israel border control allow stamping a seperate piece of paper instead of your pasport on entrance and departure, see the answer for the question http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/travel-implications-when-going-to-muslim-countries-after-a-visit-to-israel/19481#19481

Answer (score 12):

**No problem** -- the United Arab Emirates (and hence Dubai) does not care about Israeli stamps, it's only Israeli passport holders who may have a tough time.  Here's [the UAE Embassy to the US](http://www.uae-embassy.org/embassy/faqs/passports-visas) with a straightforward answer:

> Q: **I am an American traveling to the UAE, will the UAE allow me entry
>   if I have an Israeli stamp in my passport?**
>
> A: Yes.

And a [whole lot more sources here](http://www.dubaifaqs.com/israeli-stamp-passport-dubai.php) if that's not enough.

Answer (score 3):

ISRAEL NO LONGER STAMP PASSPORTS.

Instead they give you a small piece of paper containing the details of your "visa", allowed length of stay - and even a photo!  This is basically the equivalent of the stamp in your passport, and should be kept with your passport whilst in the country.

On exiting the country, they provide a second similar piece of paper which is the equivalent of your exit stamp.

As nothing is ever placed in your passport, there's no issues entering any country that may have issues with you having been to Israel previously.

Comment: As of when ? Do you have any good references or just personal experience?

Comment: Extensive personal experience, as well as that of dozens of work colleagues.

Comment: This depends on where you enter from: My entire group got a passport stamp entering from Aqaba at the Yitzhak Rabin crossing in Eilat.

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to handle the problem.

When visiting Israel asked immigration not to stamp your passport with an entry visa. They will stamp a separate piece of paper that you need to carry with you and use when you leave Israel at immigration.Therefore your trip to Israel never appears in your passport.

Many countries provided their citizens with duplicate passports. I had one United States passport that was good for use to Israel Jordan Egypt and South Africa only . And I had a second passport that was unrestricted in its usage.

When going to Israel and Jordan, I used the restricted passport. And for all other travel I use my unrestricted passport.

The State Department does give you a warning when issuing such passports that you need to be careful about which passport you present at the border control. If I had decided to use my unrestricted passport to go to Lebanon and instead presented my restricted passport I would have been royally screwed. The Lebanese authorities would not have granted me entry to Lebanon if I was lucky and if I wasn't lucky I'd be thrown into some dark prison as an Israeli spy.