# Can I be refused exit due to my place of birth?

Tags: passports, taiwan

I was born in Taiwan.    Since then, I have moved to America, obtained US citizenship, and visited Taiwan occasionally in no particular order.

My question is this. I know that men over 18 have to serve mandatory stint in the Taiwanese army.  Since all my past trips to Taiwan when I was younger than 18, now I'm not so sure.

If I go back to Taiwan to visit, with a valid US passport, would I still be prevented from leaving Taiwan due to my old citizenship with Taiwan?

EDIT: Tried editing the title to not be so specific and a bit more general, similar to [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27446/can-i-be-refused-entry-due-to-my-place-of-birth)

Comment: Do you continue to hold Taiwanese citizenship, or have you formally relinquished it?

Comment: Not sure, I'll have to check with my parents @GregHewgill. Does it matter?

Comment: Well, it looks complicated... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationality_Law_of_the_Republic_of_China

Comment: On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_without_household_registration it says "Nationals without household registration ... are also exempt from military conscription."

Comment: He definitely still has ROC nationality unless he renounces it.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Right but being born in Taiwan wouldn't he have household registration? I'm not sure how one gives up household registration.

Comment: @user102008: I'm not certain how it works in the ROC, but in the PRC "household registration" means you actually live there.

Comment: So unless I renounce my citizenship, does this mean if I ever traveled back to Taiwan, I'd have to go into mandatory service @user102008

Comment: @DISREGARDMODSACQUIREREP: Well I am not sure, because it's unclear whether you are eligible for the draft because for one thing we are not sure whether you still have Taiwan household registration (i.e. a national ID card). Also, on Wikipedia it says eligible males of draft age can't renounce ROC nationality until they complete their military obligations, so if it turns out you're eligible, I don't think renouncing helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but after I was born in Taiwan, I stayed there for a year, then I moved to America, where I've been for the last few decades

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Conscription in Taiwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_Taiwan):

> Draftable males classified as Overseas Taiwanese are exempt from the draft provided they do not reside continuously in the Taiwan Area for a) more than four months at a time for those born in 1984 and before or b) more than 183 days in a two-year period.

There is a reference on that quote but it's now a dead link. It seems likely that you would be classified as Overseas Taiwanese because you do not live in Taiwan.

Comment: But would he be classified as Overseas Taiwanese (probably meant "Overseas Chinese")?