# Travel to the US with a stamp from Israel in my passport

Tags: usa, israel, german-citizens

If you are curious and want to see a helpful comment I added (a little late): [to comment and answer on this page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83572/travel-to-the-us-with-a-stamp-from-israel-in-my-passport#comment235065_83592)

I am going to travel to Israel at the end of the year for one week.

Somewhere I read, that I could get problems with a stamp from Israel in my passport when traveling to the US again.

Also I read, that I could get the stamp on a separate paper (Though I would need two pieces because one is going to get taken away as I enter Israel at the airport).

I'm from Germany and visited the US for the first time this year and wanted to visit the US in maybe two or three years again.

Does anyone know if I'm going to face any problems at the border with a stamp from Israel?

Comment: Where did you read that lie?

Comment: Which lie? Problems with traveling to the US with a stamp or that I could get the stamp on a seperate paper? Here I found something about not getting a stamp in my passport: https://andreasmoser.blog/2012/08/23/israeli-passport-stamp/

Comment: While there are some countries where an Israeli stamp would cause problems, the US is *definitely* not one of them.

Comment: Can't find the "israel-stamp problem with the US" source again - But I'm pretty sure i read it somewhere

Comment: @TopQuestions if 2016 teached you anything it's this: do not believe everything (anything?) you read online!

Comment: Germany allows you to apply for a second (parallel valid) passport if you claim such a potential conflict, without you being required to specify details. You surely don't need to do it for US/Israel, but if you want, you can always get such a second passport.

Comment: US is pretty much Israel's biggest ally and funder. I do wonder where you heard that from.

Comment: See my [answer here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/travel-implications-when-going-to-muslim-countries-after-a-visit-to-israel/19481#19481) regarding the issue of Israeli stamps in your passport.

Comment: @TopQuestions If you're entering Israel Ben Gurion Airport, you **will not** get any stamp whatsoever, but a small loose-leaf entry slip

Comment: As a heads up, there's a lot of misinformation about Israel, and about Jews, both on the internet and on other media.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm  Misinformation about the Jewish people you say, surely you jest....../end dripping sarcasm.  Heck, there is misinformation about *insert ethnic/religious group here*, everywhere....lol   Old 40s/50s textbooks are almost hilarious.

Comment: I can think of exactly one circumstance under which an Israeli entry stamp could cause problems entering the USA: if (1) you are not a citizen of a visa-waiver country and (2) your visa application listed countries you visited and (3) you did not include your visit to Israel on such list and (4) your passport has a stamp showing entry to Israel during the time period covered by the list of visited countries submitted on the visa application... then you would probably be in some trouble for falsifying the information on your visa application. Note that the actual trouble stems from (3) not (4).

Comment: @BenVoigt I can think of another: The U.S. immigration officer is aware that Israel doesn't normally issue visa stamps and, therefore, thinks you may have faked stamps in your passport. :) I would guess that could cause **a lot** of trouble.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The Israel passport stamp may cause a entry problem with when visiting the following countries, not USA:

> there does seem to be some consensus as to which countries do restrict access. They are as follows:
>
> Syria,
> Lebanon,
> Libya,
> Kuwait,
> Iran,
> Iraq (except the northern Kurdish region),
> Sudan,
> Yemen,
>
> There have also been reports of problems entering the following countries:
>
> Saudi Arabia (reportedly not strictly enforced due to pressure by the U.S.)
> Malaysia,
> Pakistan,
> Algeria,
> Indonesia,
> U.A.E,

Source: [Onlince Resources](http://www.theexpeditioner.com/2012/03/14/are-you-banned-from-certain-countries-if-you-have-an-israeli-stamp-in-your-passport/)

However coming back to your question

> Does anyone know if I'm going to face any problems at the border with
> a stamp from Israel?

USA is the country which has recognized Israel since 31 January 1949. And in 'International recogination of Israel' doesn't say that USA doesn't accept Israeli Passport either. Therefore Israeli stamp on your German passport not a problem when entering USA.

Source: [International recognition of Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_recognition_of_Israel)

Comment: @TopQuestions welcome

Answer (score 32):

Israel never stamps passports at Ben Gurion (TLV) Airport. They always hand you a separate ticket to keep with your passport. As per the other answers, the USA is about the last place to worry about for this subject, but, in fact, there's no stamp to worry about at all.

Comment: Not true. In the last 5 years in Ben Gurion airport, I sometimes got a stamp in my passport and sometimes on a separate sheet. So better ask for the separate sheet if you want to make sure they don't stamp your passport.

Comment: Just wanted to add a little late: This was correct - I just got a little printed piece of paper, i think my passport photo and numbers as well as name and dates as I remember correctly.

Comment: @TopQuestions - for the last 2 or 3 years ( don't remember exactly ) the passport stamps have been abolished in Israel, like in many other countries,  for almost everyone except for very specific cases and special requests and in fact the officers in the booth do not even have stamps anymore.

Answer (score 29):

More than a quarter of Israeli exports go to the United States and 13% of imports come from there. Not only does a [free trade agreement](https://ustr.gov/trade-agreements/free-trade-agreements/israel-fta) exist between the USA and Israel but it was the first such agreement the USA entered into. Many large USA companies operate significant research centers there including Intel, Microsoft, Apple. Notably the Haifa research center have pulled out Intel of the Pentium 4 dead end. Whatever you think of president elect Donald Trump, it's notable he is an investor there and so is Warren Buffet and Bill Gates. The close and multifaceted economical ties would be impossible if there would be any such problems.

Oh and the military of the two country are also cooperating on many levels, see [Israel–United States military relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93United_States_military_relations).

Comment: True, USA is supposed to be strongest Isreali allay for decades

Comment: And even if Trump were not an investor and a businessman in general, he's definitely not an anti-semite... And even if he were it's exceedingly unlikely he could get a measure in place barring people from entering the country who have been to Israel, that's not something a president can just wish into existence.

Comment: @jwenting your comment from two months ago harkens from a different era. As we've just seen, the president wished a ban for seven countries into existence. And although antisemitism is not on the agenda yet, there are too many Nazi figures around him so who knows.

Answer (score 2):

Despite all the other answers and comments found here, I must interject that my friend is taken into the border office for questioning **every** time I drive with him into the United States, because he has Israeli stamps in his passport. He is Canadian; his wife is Israeli (living in Canada) and they travel to Israel on occasion.

I do not know why they do this. He has never been actually barred from entry.

Comment: If you don't know why they do this, how do you know that it's because he has Israeli stamps in his passport?

Comment: @prosfilaes Well, if it's a random search, how are the picking the same guy over and over?

Comment: @DepressedDaniel In 1963, in an underground Yale newspaper, someone with the same name promised death to the imperial pigs. Or he did, and it's worth scrutiny but they can't justify barring him. Or many years ago, a guard stopped him and left convinced he was smuggling something, so now he's permanently on a list of "guys we just KNOW are smugglers". He could be on an official shit list for any number of reasons, and especially if it's the same border post, an unofficial shit list. It could be the Israeli stamps, but it could be any number of things.

Comment: @prosfilaes because he tells me. He goes inside, they say "So, been to Israel?" and he tells them about his wife and trip and they let him go. He comes out, tells me what happened and says it happens every time.
I should have said "I don't know why they target the Israeli stamps".

Comment: @retrospectacus - Just out of curiosity - do you know if they also stop his wife with the Israeli passport ?