# Visiting both Taiwan and China having one passport

Tags: visas, passports, china, taiwan, disputed-territories

Can I expect to encounter any problem when visiting the Republic of China (Taiwan) after visiting the People's Republic of China or vice versa?

I mean, some countries have political clashes with each other, and sometimes such clashes just poison a traveller's life. It happens sometimes that a passport with stamped visa of one specific country is not even recognized as a valid document by another country.

**UPD:** I'll be most probably on Russian passport, but I believe it would be nice if you can provide any kind of information on this issue, specific to whatever citizenship - just like @Tom Squires have done. So it can be useful to any traveller as well.

Comment: can you let us know what passport you'll be on?

Comment: @MarkMayo, updated the question, thank you for the tip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

China and Taiwan, even though China does not officially acknowledge Taiwan's existence, do allow citizens from each others' country to visit. Yes, they have to jump through hoops, but it's allowed. In fact from what I've heard during my travels in Taiwan, there's a lot of economic interdependence between the two countries now.

I've also met travellers (holders of British passports) in Taiwan who've also travelled in mainland China, and they didn't report any problems of the kind that exist [when you get an Israeli stamp on your passport and some Muslim countries don't allow you](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1497/108). So while this is only anecdotal evidence, I haven't heard of this being a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Depends on the nationality of your passport but if its UK or American you should be fine (ie http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/asia/300230-any-problems-entering-china-w-taiwan-passport-stamp.html)

Comment: most probably it won't be American and definitely it won't be one of UK, but thank you for encouraging news any way)