# Visiting Taiwan, then to China

Tags: china, new-zealand, taiwan, new-zealand-citizens, disputed-territories

essentially the same question as this thread: [Visiting both Taiwan and China having one passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8597/visiting-both-taiwan-and-china-having-one-passport)

I intend to travel on a New Zealand passport from Auckland to Taiwan first, then to China, then back to Auckland. I'm aware the thread above was created in 2012 and I am wondering if the "it will be fine" view is still true for 2019.

Comment: Nothing has changed, it's still fine.

Comment: Can confirm everything was fine